# Execute multiple .jmx file in parallel

Tags: jmeter

How can I execute multiple .jmx file in parallel from terminal?
I tried using command as

```
./jmeter -n -t /path/file1.jmx /path/file2.jmx but it throws error
```

Comment: You can merge tests into one test, or run them from the command line using ant. See 
http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest and the easiest way is using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for running your existing JMeter scripts. Taurus naturally supports JMeter so you won't have change anything. The relevant Taurus YAML config file will look like:

```
---
execution:
- scenario:
    script: /path/file1.jmx
- scenario:
    script: /path/file2.jmx
- scenario:
    script: /etc
```

See [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests) article for more details on combining several tests into one with Taurus

Comment: I tried using Taurus and created .yaml file but I could not execute it. It throws error. Can you provide me the steps to create .yaml file and where should I save it?

Comment: I am not telepathic enough to troubleshoot the error without knowing its details, you need to elaborate your question and provide the error message you are getting. Also YAML syntax matters, any missing or extra space or colon and the file won't be parsed

Comment: I am getting error like:
ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "Downloads/testjmeter.yaml", line 2, column 10

Answer (score -1):

Use **Taurus** for executing multiple jmx script in parallel.

Here is the process:

1. Install [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/) Either by installer or do manually.

If you are installing manually and please follow these steps:

- Download Python from their download section.
- Go to Python>Scripts installed folder and run following commands:

  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip install lxml
  - pip install psutil
  - Now install Taurus by "pip install bzt"
  - pip install --upgrade bzt
- After installation you well get **.bzt folder & .bzt-rc** in your home directory.
- Edit **.bzt-rc** and uncomment:[following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YfWb.jpg)

  **Note**: According to your **jdk** give version e.g: if you have jdk 7 give version: 3.0(Since Jmeter is dependent on jdk version,please careful here).
- After doing all steps now you are ready to execute multiple jmx file in following way:

  - bzt a.jmx b.jmx c.jmx

This way you can execute multiple jmx file at one instance.

If you have further query please reach to me by either by Email or any other social sites.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.